# Cannot call res.send() within promise

Tags: express, mongoose, promise

I am refactoring my code from using callbacks. Of course, everything in this first solution works as expected:

```
        const newUser = new User({
            email,
            password,
        })

        User.exists({ email }, (err, userExists) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }
            if (userExists) {
                return res.status(400).send("A user with that email already exists")
            }
            newUser.save()
                .then(result => console.log('new user successfully registered!:', result))
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('Cannot save user: ', err)
                })

            var profile = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password', 'extra')

            res.status(201).send({
                id_token: createIdToken(profile),
                access_token: createAccessToken()
            })
        })
```

Here is after the refactor:

```
        User.exists({ email })
            .then(userExists => {
                if (userExists) {
                    res.status(400).send("A user with that email already exists")
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                const newUser = new User({
                    email,
                    password,
                })
                return newUser
            })
            .then(newUser => {
                console.log('newUser: ', newUser);
                return newUser.save()
            })
            .then(result => console.log('new user successfully registered!:', result))
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Cannot save user: ', err)
                return next(err)
            })
```

However, this does not work. I've isolated down where in the promise chain the error occurs, and it happens when I try to send the response back to the client `res.send`

The error I get is:
C

> cannot save user:  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/home/kyle/programming/projects/never-forget/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/home/kyle/programming/projects/never-forget/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>       at /home/kyle/programming/projects/never-forget/server/src/controllers/users.js:47:22
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:

`cannot set headers after they are sent` is self-explanatory, but I do not see where in my program I have attempted to send headers after the request is sent. Seeing as `res.send` ends the request, I don't see what else should be included.

Comment: You need to show us the code for the ENTIRE request handler for us to spot your mistake.  This is a very common error when you aren't handling asynchronous results properly.  But, we need to see the whole request handler to see where things have gone wrong.  In the refactor code, for a successful `user.save()` you don't send ANY response so clearly this code isn't causing the error you see.  We need to see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i can think of is :

In callback implementation, when `userExists` is true, you are calling `return res.status(400).send("A user with that email already exists")` which ends the callback and `res.status(201).send({...})` doesn't get called.

But, In promise implementation, when `userExists` is true, both of them will be called.

So, you can throw an error after `return res.status(400).send("A user with that email already exists")`, and catch that in catch block where it will end the main callback i.e. by `return next(err);`

Comment: I've never heard of this functionality of promises. Nevertheless, I have tried your suggested solution by adding `throw new Error('user already exists')` within the conditional, but I am still facing the same issue. Thanks for giving it a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
User.exists({ email })
.then(userExists => {
    if (userExists.length >= 1) {
        return res.status(409).json({
            message: "Mail exists"
        });
    } else {
        newUser.save()
            .then(result => console.log('new user successfully registered!:', result))
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Cannot save user: ', err)
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. unfortunately same errors persist as before